# Disable MultiViews in Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, configuration, webserver, multiviews

We are getting "Alternates" from our Apache server for the 404 error documents and would requires to disable them. For a GET request on the server, we get the following section in our response header

```
Alternates: {"HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var" 1 {type text/html} {charset iso-8859-2} {language cs} {length 745}}, {"HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var" 1 {type text/html} {charset iso-8859-1} {language de} {length 766}},.....
```

We have been told that this is an issue with MultiViews and we need to disable it. We have Disable this

```
Options IncludesNoExec -MultiViews
```

But we still receive alternates in our response header.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by removing the alternates in the server configuration and restarting the server.

```
#ErrorDocument 404 HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var.en 
#ErrorDocument 404 HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var.de
```